# What is the efficient/best way to access a user provided property of a user provided class dynamically?

Tags: java

I'm writing a generic library which must access a particular property of a user provided class's instance. I need to get both of these, the class (Say C) and its property (say p), as input from the user. This should be fast as this will be done hundreds of times per second.

Reflection is out of the league as it is too slow and to be used only for the last resort. I had two approaches in mind:

- The class must implement a functional interface I which provides a getter for b.
- (coveted) User provides some Function F along with the class instance which, when applied on the class, returns the property b.

Approach 1:

```java
public MyClass<T extends SomeInterface> {
```

This solves the problem as I can access the property of the user provided type in the class as:

```java
T obj;
obj.getRequiredProperty();
```

Approach 2:

```java
SomeType j = new MyClass<SomeType>(SomeFunction);
```

This should solve the problem by returning the required property when `SomeFunction` is applied to the class object.

```java
Object o = j.apply(SomeFunction);
```

Approach 1 doesn't work because it restricts the user from using classes which he can't modify to implement the required interface.
For example if a class is in a third party library, the user can not modify the class/POJO to implement the interface so that the class becomes usable. This can be a limitation but not a blocker.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @RealSkeptic My question is, Is there any straight forward way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use approach 1. Both approach 1 and 2 would require a user to modify the class they are working with, but approach 1 is more readable/maintainable. If for example, you realised you needed many of these required properties, you would need many functions passed in the constructor, which would become unmanageable.

If the user cannot modify the classes he is working with, he can extend/wrap them. As far as I am aware these are your only options. And it is generally always better to avoid reflection.